# Why do I say int *p = NULL in the declaration, but p != NULL in the test, why not *p != NULL to match the declaration?

Tags: c++, pointers

in c++, if we assign a pointer value to `NULL` ,why ***dont*** we check if `*p!=NULL` and instead `p!=NULL`?

I found this code in a tutorial.

```
int *p = NULL;
char *q = NULL;
// ...
if (p!=NULL) cout << *p;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In my opinion, it's better to simply use 0 rather than NULL. C++0x has a real null pointer constant, and there you should use it. But in C++, I think 0 is less error prone than NULL. NULL gets defined to all kinds of interesting and odd things.

Comment: @Omnifarious: `0` is exactly as error prone as `NULL`, since the only valid definitions for `NULL` are zero-valued integer literals.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: I've seen NULL defined as `((void *)0)` in places.

Comment: @Omnifarious: that's fine in C, but invalid in C++ where `void *` can't be converted to other pointer types. In C++, `NULL` can only be a zero-valued integer literal.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: This is true, but there are implementations out there that still do it the C way. And re-defining NULL yourself is a poor idea too. So, sticking with just plain old 0 is the best bet.

Comment: If you wrote it `int* p = NULL;`, there would be less of a problem. You assign NULL to p, not *p.

Comment: @Bo Persson - I disagree with this usage. What does `int* p, q;` mean?

Comment: @Omnifarius: And I disagree with THAT usage. :-) It should be `int* p = NULL; int* q = NULL;`. Problem solved (and no uninitialized pointers either).

Comment: "if we assign a pointer value to `NULL`"... we don't. We assign `NULL` to a pointer!

Answer (score 15):

The `*` is doing two different things. When you declare the variable, it means the variable is a pointer. When you use the variable, it means "dereference", that is take the value at the location the pointer is pointing to. Two totally different meanings.

Comment: +1 This is much better than the currently highly voted answer. C++ declarator syntax is, IMHO, weird, and this should be pointed out. Also, some people adopt a declarator style of `int* p;`, but I hate that because the `*` refers to a single variable, not all the variables in the comma separated list. It doesn't belong with the `int`.

Comment: @Frustrated Coder: Don't forget to [mark the answer that helped you most as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)/

Answer (score 11):

Because `p` is the pointer, and `*p` is the object that it points to.

Comment: Right. It's perfectly fine for a pointer to point at a location that contains 0 (the usual value for `NULL`).

Comment: -1 : The OP is confused as to why the * is in the declarator and doesn't seem to have the same meaning there as elsewhere. This answer, while being exactly correct, doesn't help with the question.

Comment: @Omnifarious: the question didn't say that until you edited the title.

Comment: I edited the title to reflect what was in the question so it would be easier for people to find. Also, @Frustrated Coder's response to @Mark Ransom's answer indicate that I correctly discerned what question was being asked.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are confused. The code from the tutorial is **creating** a pointer and initializing it to `NULL`, then later it is testing if it is `NULL`. The reason why you don't check if `*p != NULL` is because that would be testing if what it points to is `NULL`, and not test if the pointer itself is `NULL`.

Of course you can choose to test `*p` against any value you like provided it is a valid pointer... It all depends on what you want to do.

**EDIT:**

You didn't assign `NULL` to `*p`, you assigned it to `p`. The statement `int *p = NULL;` is the same as writing:

```
int *p;
p = NULL;
```

`int *` is the type.

Basically, when you write: `if(p != NULL)` you are simply testing if `p` points to a place such that it is safe to use `*p`.

Comment: yes thats right sorry i mistyped earlier please see the modified question.

Comment: so basically my question is why dont we check if *p=NULL and instead check p!=NULL. Because initially we assigned *p=NULL.

Comment: So when we assign *p=NULL, does it set both value and location of p to NULL?

Comment: @Frustrated Coder: `*p = NULL` by itself simply assigned `NULL` to what `p` points to. `int *p = NULL` creates a pointer of type `int *` and assigns `NULL` to the pointer.

Comment: @Frustrated: The location of `p` is another address, the value of `p` is null, and doesn't point at a location (that's what null is).

Comment: @Frustrated Code: I think you are getting confused by the usage of `*` in two contexts (type declaration and dereferencing). If I wrote it like this would be more clear? `int* p = NULL;` (it means the same thing as `int *p = NULL;`).

Comment: yes...I guess & operator also confused me for a while when it was actually used for referencing and pass by reference!!!!!!! :D:D:D

Answer (score 1):

The code is declaring a int pointer through the statement `int *p = NULL`. Please note that these statements are equivalent:

```
int *p = NULL;
int* p = NULL;
```

And both of these mean that p is a pointer to an integer which further means that p holds the address of an integer. So, when the code later checks for

```
if(p != NULL)
```

it is basically checking that whether the address contained in this pointer is NULL or not. I hope it makes things clear.

Answer (score 0):

Because `p` is a pointer; it is a variable that holds a memory address of some object.

The code checks if the pointer is pointing to an object and, if it is, shows the value of that object on the screen.

---

```
if (p != NULL) // "if p is pointing to an object then ..."
{
    cout << *p; // "show me the value of that object on the screen"
}
```

- `p` is the address of the object
- `*p` is the value of the object, called dereferencing